# Loading a report with Sub reports with Same RecordSelectionFormula

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

Im trying to load a Crystal Report file `ReportA.rpt` with 2 subreports `A-1.rpt` and `A-2.rpt`.

```
CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()

    rptdocument1.Load(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "ReportA.rpt")
    rptdocument1.RecordSelectionFormula = "{tbl_PV.PV_NUM}= 'PV2015-09-004'"
    rptdocument2.Load(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "A-1.rpt")
    rptdocument2.RecordSelectionFormula = "{tbl_PV.PV_NUM}= 'PV2015-09-004'"
    rptdocument.Load(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "A-2.rpt")
    rptdocument.RecordSelectionFormula = "{tbl_PV.PV_NUM}= 'PV2015-09-004'"

CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptdocument
```

Im loading the two subreports into two separate `ReportDocument`. Then Loading the main report file `RerportA` to a `CrystalReportViewer1`

Im getting the wrong records from my database. Im new to working with Subreports.

Comment: Have you linked main report and sub report

Comment: @Siva How exactly you do that?